# Why number of executors shown in Spark Web UI and rest UI is constant always , when dynamic allocation is enabled

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a Spark Streaming application with batch duration of 1 minute, and I have dynamic allocation enabled with executorIdleRunTime equal to 5 seconds. I can see in event timeline that they about 4000 many executors allocated and removed but in executors I always see 102 number of executors.What can be the reason of that.Rest API gives the same data but executor is there is different.

[image]

[image]

I have attached the respective snapshots for better understanding of the question.