# Spark rest api not updating while application is running

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a Spark Streaming application and constantly monitoring the rest api data , but to my surprise it is not updating , I thought it updates with the constantly after some events.If this is not the case then how frequently it updates.

Comment: That might be a question for the user or even the dev mailing list. Maybe they can help you out: https://spark.apache.org/community.html

Comment: @maasg one more doubt I have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012864/why-number-of-executors-shown-in-spark-web-ui-and-rest-ui-is-constant-always-w    I have tried to explain the problem clearly

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know. It would require research, access to the cluster, etc... etc...